# Getting invalid number error while using alias for combining my results in sql

Tags: oracle

```
select id+','+DISPLAY_TO as details from n_note where id=123456;
```

I am ending up with the below error msg

```
"ORA-01722: invalid number"
```

I'm using sqlplus

Comment: what is the type of the fields `id` and `DISPLAY_TO?`

Answer (score 3):

To concatenate strings, you have to use the concatenation [operator ||](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/operators003.htm):

```
select id || ',' || DISPLAY_TO as details from n_note where id=123456;
```

Answer (score 0):

Other than the wrong concatenation operator used in your query (it should be `||`), you are getting this error cause; you are trying

```
select id+','+DISPLAY_TO
```

Here, most probably `id` is numeric column and `DISPLAY_TO` is a string column; and while trying to concatenate it's trying to convert `DISPLAY_TO` column to integer and failing with that error.

As stated here [Oracle/PLSQL: ORA-01722 Error](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora01722.php)

> You executed a SQL statement that tried to convert a string to a
>   number, but it was unsuccessful.